# How do I make this tab animate up with jquery?

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate

I would like to have this tab animate when hovered over

Before:[image: before]

On hover:[image: after]

How do I go about this with jquery?

```
<div class="recruiterLink">
<a href="http://mydomain.com/recruiter/">
<span>Recruiting?</span>
<br>
Advertise a vacancy »
</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go this way :

```
$(".recruiterLink").hover(function(){
 $(this).stop().animate({"top" : "-20px"});
}, function(){
 $(this).stop().animate({"top": "0"});
});
```

This means your div.recruiterLink should have a positioning

```
.recruiterLink
{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Would this still work if the div.recruiterLink was absolutely positioned?

Comment: Yes ! It will work if it's relative or absolute. But then you should have a wrapper around your menu, with position relative so the button will not be positioned absolutely to the page, but to its wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

this could be a starter of what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tab-to-animate').hover(function() {

        // this anonymous function is invoked when
        // the mouseover event of the tab is fired

        // you will need to adjust the second px value to
        // fit the dimensions of your image
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'center 0px');

    }, function() {

        // this anonymous function is invoked when
        // the mouseout event of the tab is fired

        // you will need to adjust the second px value to
        // fit the dimensions of your image
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'center -20px');

    });

});
```

sorry misread the question this code should do move the div as a whole assuming that you have it pushed down initially using the position: relative css property.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.recruiterLink').hover(function() {

        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'top' : 0
        });

    }, function() {

        $(this).css({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'top' : 20
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: The `position: relative` for your second code is repetitive - you can move it outside the `hover` function there.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the position: relative is repetitive?

Comment: because it can be set using css

Comment: How can I add animation to this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="recruiterLink">
<a href="http://mydomain.com/recruiter/">
<span>Recruiting?</span>
<div class="hover-item" style="display:none;">Advertise a vacancy »</div>
</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".recruiterLink").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".hover-item").toggle();
}, 
function() {
  $(this).find(".hover-item").toggle();
});
```

You can also add some animation effects, if you want.

Comment: You could use the `hover(handlerInOut(eventObject))` form since both callbacks are identical.